# JavaScript that moves a webpage to a certain part of a list based on what key is pressed

Tags: javascript

I have a table with like 200 rows sorted by column A.  I’d love to be able to hit the “M” key and have the first row starting with “M” be at the top of the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using pure javascript or libraries, jquery etc?

Comment: The answer to your question is: Yes. // And now, please go read [ask].

Comment: Thanks csjdp and CBroe. I develop the webpages by ASP.NET + javascript. No jQuery at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure it's possible. The first thing to do is to intercept the click on the page, if you are using jQuery something like this should work:

```
// Ask jQuery to listen for keypress on the page
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  // Which character was pressed ?
  var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  // Next find the first item in the column that start with the letter

  var rows = $('table tr');
  for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    var row = $(rows[i]);
    var td = $('td', row).first();
    var textInRow = $(td).html();
    if(textInRow[0] == c){
        // Founded !
        var scrollTop = row.offset().top;
        $('html, body').scrollTop(scrollTop);
        break;
    }

  }

});
```

Consider that I haven't tried the code by myself, it's more a suggestion ;-)
Also consider to add more checks, like to check if the textInRow has a text longer than zero before requesting textInRow[0]. I've left some checks to leave the code more clear.

Let me know if this is working

Comment: Thanks. wezzy. I will try it.

Comment: Sorry for feedback lately, it works perfect. Thanks Wezzy.